# Can anyone translate the writing on the back of this postcard? It's from the 1920's

Tags: translation, history, handwriting

Can anyone translate the writing on the back of this postcard? It's from the 1920's. I have tried to google things like Vindhimy Farmanburg but no luck.

Here are the photos of the postcard[image]

[image]

Comment: Jennenberg? Eigentlich buchstabengetreu "Iennenberg"?

Comment: Would it be possible to add an image of the complete postcard (front and back)? Could be helpful...

Comment: @Jan Sure about "Fennenberg"? To me, it could also be "Tannenberg". Maybe even this one: http://www.gemeinde-tannenberg.de/

Comment: Ich lese zwar Zannenberg (oder ~burg, ~borg), aber Google verbessert zu Tannenberg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text reads as follows:

> Siedlung Tannenberg
>
> leider fehlt unser Haus darauf

The reading *Tannenberg* is more likely than *Tennenberg* when you compare with other instances of *e* and *a.*

The reading *darauf* is more likely than *drauf* when you compare with other instances of *r.*

Comment: Eigentlich stehen in der zweiten Zeile nicht sechs, sondern nur fünf Wörter, nämlich: »leider fehlt unser Haus drauf«.

Comment: @Jan: Danke für die Korrektur. Selbstverständlich ist es *fehlt* und nicht *‌*sieht man [...] nicht* – ich hätte es noch einmal lesen sollen …

Comment: Just noticed regarding the question: »Can anyone _translate_ ...«

Comment: translated to english? So it's: "Siedlung Tannenberg, unfortunately our house is missing on it" (on the photo)

Comment: @Campbell If the given answer answers your question, you can kindly accept it as the solution by clicking the hook under vote up/down arrows.

Answer (score 1):

translated to english? So it's: "Siedlung Tannenberg, unfortunately our house is missing on it" (on the photo) – Celophysis Mar 2 at 12:40